# Appliances and power station frequency compatibility

Tags: appliances

I am planning to buy an [Anker Power Station](https://www.anker.com/products/a1751?variant=41686355771542).

The US website it says that the power output is

> AC Output/AC: 110 V~ 4.54 A, 50 Hz/60 Hz, 500 W

I'm buying the unit here in Middle East and the unit back label says

> AC Output/AC: 220-240 V~ 2.27 A, 50 Hz, 500 W

I talked to Anker support and they said it is 50 Hz/60 Hz. I'm a bit doubtful because maybe the tech is checking the same webpage I am checking and not really looking at variation models they have in their library.

Our appliances are all 50 Hz/60 Hz.

In case the real output of the power station is **50 Hz** not **50 Hz/60 Hz**, will it be a problem?

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question? What's a "battery frequency"?

Comment: It will be putting out either 50Hz or 60Hz, most likely depending on where you are buying it.  50/60Hz as an output frequency is meaningless.  Do you need 50Hz, 60Hz, or don't care?

Comment: 99 % of all appliances on the market won't care if you feed it 50 or 60 Hz. In the <500 W range, probably even higher.

Comment: @Lundin sorry if I said something wrong in the title. I'm not an electrician. Anker power station is a battery and 50Hz/60Hz is a frequency I assume.

Comment: @winny, thanks for that input, I guess now I have 99% confidence I can buy the unit. Would you like to put that as an answer and I will accept it? Thanks

Comment: The frequency refers to the VAC (sine wave) that should be used to supply the product, not to the product itself.

Comment: @Lundin, Im not concern on the product (anker) because the charger it says 50Hz/60Hz. It will charge just OK. I am concern on the appliances I will put in the AC output of the Power Station.

Comment: You keep saying "appliance", which in American English usage usually implies something with a motor or a heater in it, like a toaster or a blender.  Such appliances often need a high inrush current -- i.e., a blender that's rated at 1.5A will draw more than that at first while the motor is spinning up, and then settle out to 1.5A or less.  This won't cause any problems on a normal power grid -- but a UPS might shut itself down on that initial overload.  Fortunately, Anker is a good brand, so it probably won't break -- it'll just shut down each time you try to run that appliance.

Comment: "50Hz/60Hz" is not **a** frequency, it's 2 different frequencies. Your device will provide an output which is either one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An appliance label that reads 50 Hz / 60 Hz is informing you that it can accept either frequency, not that it needs both.

If you buy a power unit which provides 50 Hz AC, you must check the label of any device you want to plug into it, and ensure that the device can accept 50 Hz.

Equally important (if not more so) you **must** match the voltage rating, and ensure you do not exceed the maximum power rating. This device

> AC Output/AC: 220-240 V~ 2.27 A, 50 Hz, 500 W

cannot power a 110 V device, or any device that draws more than 500 W (approximately 2 A at 240 V). It will provide 50 Hz AC at 230 V, up to about 2 A.

Comment: Thanks. That is the clarity I needed. and Yes, we live in region where grid is providing 220V with frequent failure, hence i needed the power station. Our appliances are all 220V compatible.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if the appliances supports only 60Hz and I put it in this power station that output only 50Hz, will it brick the appliances?

Comment: @Wayne 98 % chance you won't. If a manufacturer wants to save a few bucks on certification despite the product can cover 85-264 V and 45-65 Hz, they'll just mark it as 120 V 60 Hz for the US market and 230 V 50 Hz for the EU market. This goes for any switch mode power supply and universal motors. Induction motors are the obvious exception to this, but it's mighty rare that you would find one in the <500 W category in the first place.